# Python IMAP: =?utf-8?Q? in subject string

Tags: python, email, character-encoding, imap, mime

I am displaying new email with `IMAP`, and everything looks fine, except for one message subject shows as:

`=?utf-8?Q?Subject?=`

How can I fix it?

Comment: *"How can I fix it?"* - Why do you assume that it is broken?

Comment: It should show just "Subject" - what's inside the =?utf-8?Q? ... ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Difference_between_Q-encoding_and_quoted-printable

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In MIME terminology, those encoded chunks are called encoded-words.  You can decode them like this:

```
import email.header
text, encoding = email.header.decode_header('=?utf-8?Q?Subject?=')[0]
```

Check out the docs for [`email.header`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html) for more details.

Comment: In both Python 2 and Python 3, `email.header.decode_header` (with lower-case `m`) is the generic name. In addition, in your code, `text` is not actually a text, but instead a bytes variable.

Answer (score 15):

This is a MIME [encoded-word](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-2). You can parse it with [`email.header`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/email.header.html):

```
import email.header

def decode_mime_words(s):
    return u''.join(
        word.decode(encoding or 'utf8') if isinstance(word, bytes) else word
        for word, encoding in email.header.decode_header(s))

print(decode_mime_words(u'=?utf-8?Q?Subject=c3=a4?=X=?utf-8?Q?=c3=bc?='))
```

Comment: Could you rewrite that in a more Pythonic fashion?

Comment: @wbg What's not Pythonic about this code? What would you change?
Looking at it now, it seems rather well-written to me, and a paragon of Python's expressiveness. Maybe the [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) is tripping up @deterjan?
If you're just targeting Python 3, you can skip the `if isinstance(word, bytes) else word` and the `u` before the `'`; this code has been engineered to work on both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 15):

The text is encoded as a MIME *encoded-word*.  This is a mechanism defined in [RFC2047](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2047) for encoding headers that contain non-ASCII text such that the encoded output contains only ASCII characters.

In Python 3.3+, the parsing classes and functions in [email.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html) automatically decode "encoded words" in headers if their `policy` argument is set to `policy.default`

```
>>> import email
>>> from email import policy

>>> msg = email.message_from_file(open('message.txt'), policy=policy.default)
>>> msg['from']
'Pepé Le Pew <pepe@example.com>'
```

The parsing classes and functions are:

- [email.parser.BytesParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.BytesParser)
- [email.parser.Parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.Parser)
- [email.message_from_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_bytes)
- [email.message_from_binary_file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_binary_file)
- [email.message_from_string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_string)
- [email.message_from_file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_file)

Confusingly, up to at least Python 3.10, the default policy for these parsing functions is not `policy.default`, but `policy.compat32`, which does *not* decode "encoded words".

```
>>> msg = email.message_from_file(open('message.txt'))
>>> msg['from']
'=?utf-8?q?Pep=C3=A9?= Le Pew <pepe@example.com>'
```

Answer (score 6):

Try [Imbox](https://github.com/martinrusev/imbox)

Because `imaplib` is a very excessive low level library and returns results which are hard to work with

**Installation**

`pip install imbox`

**Usage**

```
from imbox import Imbox

with Imbox('imap.gmail.com',
        username='username',
        password='password',
        ssl=True,
        ssl_context=None,
        starttls=False) as imbox:

    all_inbox_messages = imbox.messages()
    for uid, message in all_inbox_messages:
        message.subject
```

Comment: +1 truly this is for humans. Indeed imbox was able to decode otherwise base64-encoded (in imaplib and the like) subject and other fields on-the-fly. However, be aware if some field is missing the KeyError will be thrown.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, decoding this to an approximated string is as easy as:

```py
from email.header import decode_header, make_header

decoded = str(make_header(decode_header("=?utf-8?Q?Subject?=")))
```

See the documentation of [`decode_header`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.header.html#email.header.decode_header) and [`make_header`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.header.html#email.header.make_header).

Answer (score 0):

High level IMAP lib may be useful here: [imap_tools](https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools)

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

# get list of email subjects from INBOX folder
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    subjects = [msg.subject for msg in mailbox.fetch()]
```

- Parsed email message attributes
- Query builder for searching emails
- Actions with emails: copy, delete, flag, move, seen
- Actions with folders: list, set, get, create, exists, rename, delete, status
- No dependencies