# I am trying to print message from email, but encoding isn't working correctly

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to print message from email. I am using imaplib to work with imap server.

Code example below.

```
def fetch_msg(conn, index):
    status, msg_data = conn.fetch(index, '(RFC822)')

    if status != 'OK': return None
    for resp_part in msg_data:
        if isinstance(resp_part, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_string(resp_part[1])

            for header in ['subject', 'to', 'from', 'date']:
                print('%-8s: %s' % (header.upper(), msg[header]))
```

I get this result:

```
SUBJECT : =?UTF-8?B?0JHQu9Cw0LPQvtC00LDRgNC40Lwg0LfQsCDQv9C+0LrRg9C/0LrRgyE=?=
TO      : example@mail.bk
FROM    : noreply@steampowered.com
DATE    : Tue, 17 Nov 2015 06:05:13 -0800
```

How can I get SUBJECT with a normal view? I am using utf-8 encoding in the source file.

Comment: import sys, put a reload(sys) line at the start of the script then put sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8') after that line.

Comment: Don't use `setdefaultencoding`. It will [cause problems](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/). Instead specify the encoding. Decode early, unicode everywhere, encode late. This is how you properly deal with unicode.

Comment: n1c9 Unfortunately it's don't work.

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12904228/4241180)