# How to decode encode e-mail subject line in python?

Tags: python, email, utf-8, decode

How do I detect encode e-mail subject in python and also decode it? I see code in PHP mb_decode_mimeheader(); but not map code in python.

This is my code:

```
print "=============Subject==============="
print  mystr = email_message['Subject']
```

This is output:

```
=============Subject===============
'=?UTF-8?Q?Fry=27s=2DDay=20Deal=20Alert=21=20         More=20Smokin?=^M
=?UTF-8?Q?=27=20HOT=20Summer=20Deals=20Have=20        Arrived=21=20=24299=205?=^M
=?UTF-8?Q?5=2DInch=20RCA=20Full=20HD=20 LED=20TV=20=7C=20FREE=20Kasper?=^M
=?UTF-8?Q?sky=20Internet=20        Security=202016=2A=20=26=20Much=20More?='
```

This is the e-mail display subject(>75) which I want to get:
Fry's-Day Deal Alert! More Smokin' HOT Summer Deals Have Arrived! $299 55-Inch RCA Full HD LED TV | FREE Kaspersky Internet Security 2016* & Much More
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Python 3: Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/65474977/13125111:

```py
from email.header import decode_header, make_header

def decode_mimeheader(h: str) -> str:
    return str(make_header(decode_header(h)))

mystr = '''=?UTF-8?Q?Fry=27s=2DDay=20Deal=20Alert=21=20         More=20Smokin?=^M
=?UTF-8?Q?=27=20HOT=20Summer=20Deals=20Have=20        Arrived=21=20=24299=205?=^M
=?UTF-8?Q?5=2DInch=20RCA=20Full=20HD=20 LED=20TV=20=7C=20FREE=20Kasper?=^M
=?UTF-8?Q?sky=20Internet=20        Security=202016=2A=20=26=20Much=20More?='''
decoded_mystr = decode_mimeheader(mystr)
```

Now `decoded_mystr` is `"Fry's-Day Deal Alert!          More Smokin ^M ' HOT Summer Deals Have         Arrived! $299 5 ^M 5-Inch RCA Full HD  LED TV | FREE Kasper ^M sky Internet         Security 2016* & Much More"`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [decode_header](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html#email.header.decode_header) like:

```
>>> from email.header import decode_header
>>> decode_header(email_message['Subject'])
[(b"Fry's-Day Deal Alert!          More Smokin", 'utf-8'),
(b'^M', None),
(b"' HOT Summer Deals Have         Arrived! $299 5", 'utf-8'),
(b'^M', None),
(b'5-Inch RCA Full HD  LED TV | FREE Kasper', 'utf-8'),
(b'^M', None),
(b'sky Internet         Security 2016* & Much More', 'utf-8')]
```